# Node.js IMAP ECONNREFUSED

Tags: node.js, typescript, imap, econnrefused

Why can't I event change the port number? I have already close all the firewall

CODE:

```
var imapConfig = new Imap({
    user: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    password: "xxxxxxxxx",
    server: "imap.gmail.com",
    port: 993,
    tls: true,
    debug: console.log,
});

clog(levels.NORMAL, "Email connection");

const imap = new Imap(imapConfig);
```

RESULT:

```
[connection] Error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:143
20231207101555.140000N Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:143
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1159:16) {
errno: -4078,
code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '127.0.0.1',
port: 143,
source: 'socket'
}
[connection] Closed
```

can someone tell or help me to solve this problem? ty

Comment: The error clearly shows that you are trying to connect to 127.0.0.1 (localhost) port 143, not the address you are showing in your code. Why are you trying to create an `Imap()` of an `Imap()`?

Comment: oh! i didt notice it. Thank for your help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try

```
var imapConfig = {
    user: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    password: "xxxxxxxxx",
    server: "imap.gmail.com",
    port: 993,
    tls: true,
    debug: console.log,
};

clog(levels.NORMAL, "Email connection");

const imap = new Imap(imapConfig);
```

Comment: Thank you!!!
i followed ur code.

[connection] Error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:993
20231208011600.215000N Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:993
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1159:16) {
  errno: -4078,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 993,
  source: 'socket'
}
[connection] Closed

now it's mean i cant connect to the gmail server?